# Why isn't VLC media player changing the playback speed?

Tags: vlc-media-player

Some old versions of VideoLAN VLC media player can adjust the playback speed of streaming video with the keys <kbd>[</kbd>, <kbd>]</kbd>, gray <kbd>+</kbd>, gray<kbd>-</kbd>.

It works in Windows with VLC 2.0.5.
However, VLC 2.1.3 and 2.2.1 under the same Windows 7 does not change the playback speed. VLC 2.2.1 under Windows 8.1 also does not change the playback speed. When pressing the keys, OSD messages appear, but playback speed does not change. This was observed on various computers with Intel low-end graphics cards.

Under Linux Ubuntu 16.04 I tried VLC 2.2.2 and 2.2.4, and it also does not change the speed. Onscreen messages appear "Speed: 1.5x", but the ratio in status bar stays constant. In Preferences > Input/Codecs I entered "Playback speed" as 1.6. It shows as "1.6" in the status bar, but playback actually happens only at normal speed. This is under Compiz/Unity with video cards Intel X3100 and Geforce 9400GT (with restart in between).

The stream comes from **Wowza Media Server 2.2.4 build27452**:

[rtsp://85.9.209.25:1935/live/mobile.stream](http://rtsp://85.9.209.25:1935/live/mobile.stream)

Is there some parameter that I can adjust to make speed changes work? Can I at least somehow narrow down the problem, what should I change? As I understand, for everyone else speed adjustements work?

Comment: Are you playing a file or a stream? More details about the video source may help.

Comment: @A.Loiseau This is the stream that fails to accelerate (Cyclops cam): rtsp://85.9.209.25:1935/live/mobile.stream